# Append multiple values in dictionary but avoid repeated elements in the value of the dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have list like this:

```
[('0023_RIGHT_CC', [(2574, 2798), (1324, 1545)]),
 ('0021_LEFT_CC', [(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(911, 1135), (0, 86)]),
 ('0026_LEFT_CC', [(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)]),
 ('0021_RIGHT_CC', [(2170, 2314), (1642, 1795)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)]),
 ('0021_LEFT_CC', [(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)]),
 ('0021_RIGHT_CC', [(2170, 2314), (1642, 1795)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(911, 1135), (0, 86)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)]),
 ('0018_RIGHT_CC', [(1388, 1653), (1894, 2197)]),
 ('0023_RIGHT_CC', [(2574, 2798), (1324, 1545)]),
 ('0026_LEFT_CC', [(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)])]
```

from this I want to create a dictionary like this.. for example;

```
0106_LEFT_CC: [[(911, 1135), (0, 86)], [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)], [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)]]
```

Please note that the repeated elements in the `value` of the dictionary should be avoided. 
I did as follow;

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in data:
    d[key].append(value)
```

and I got the following result.

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'0023_RIGHT_CC': [[(2574, 2798), (1324, 1545)],
              [(2574, 2798), (1324, 1545)]],
             '0021_LEFT_CC': [[(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)],
              [(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)]],
             '0106_LEFT_CC': [[(911, 1135), (0, 86)],
              [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)],
              [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)],
              [(911, 1135), (0, 86)],
              [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)],
              [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)]],
             '0026_LEFT_CC': [[(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)],
              [(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)]],
             '0021_RIGHT_CC': [[(2170, 2314), (1642, 1795)],
              [(2170, 2314), (1642, 1795)]],
             '0018_RIGHT_CC': [[(1388, 1653), (1894, 2197)]]})
```

But the result shows for example, in the `key` `0106_LEFT_CC`, some `values` are repeated. How to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ekrem DİNÇEL has already supplied a fully functional solution that deserves selection. Nonetheless, purely for OP's reference purposes, I post an alternative solution that avoids the repeated casting from `list` to `set`, and vice versa.

That is, if you are okay with the values of the resulting dictionary being a simple `set` instead of a list, you can simply initialize the `defaultdict` to work with `set` values and deal with duplicate elements.

```
d = defaultdict(set)

for key, values in data:
    for value in values:
        d[key].add(value)
```

The result:

```
{'0023_RIGHT_CC': {(1324, 1545), (2574, 2798)}, '0021_LEFT_CC': {(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)}, '0106_LEFT_CC': {(0, 86), (964, 1102), (1679, 1833), (65, 160), (911, 1135), (1091, 1198)}, '0026_LEFT_CC': {(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)}, '0021_RIGHT_CC': {(1642, 1795), (2170, 2314)}, '0018_RIGHT_CC': {(1388, 1653), (1894, 2197)}}
```

---

**EDIT**

This implementation checks for whether or not a duplicate value exists in the nested list and appends the value only if it is a non-duplicate. This way, we can preserve the tuple data structure as specified. Note, however, that this implementation is slightly inefficient due to the fact that the `in` operation takes linear time on `list` (as opposed to constant time on `set`).

```
d = defaultdict(list)

for key, value in data:
    if value not in d[key]:
        d[key].append(value)
```

The result:

```
{'0023_RIGHT_CC': [[(2574, 2798), (1324, 1545)]], '0021_LEFT_CC': [[(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)]], '0106_LEFT_CC': [[(911, 1135), (0, 86)], [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)], [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)]], '0026_LEFT_CC': [[(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)]], '0021_RIGHT_CC': [[(2170, 2314), (1642, 1795)]], '0018_RIGHT_CC': [[(1388, 1653), (1894, 2197)]]}
```

Comment: sorry this is not the one I mentioned... I want to preserve the square bracket tuples [(911, 1135), (0, 86)]. repeated square bracket tuples must be avoided.

Answer (score 4):

You can convert them into a `set` and then to a `list` again. This will get you rid of repeated elements.

```py
from collections import defaultdict

data = [('0023_RIGHT_CC', [(2574, 2798), (1324, 1545)]),
 ('0021_LEFT_CC', [(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(911, 1135), (0, 86)]),
 ('0026_LEFT_CC', [(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)]),
 ('0021_RIGHT_CC', [(2170, 2314), (1642, 1795)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)]),
 ('0021_LEFT_CC', [(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)]),
 ('0021_RIGHT_CC', [(2170, 2314), (1642, 1795)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(911, 1135), (0, 86)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)]),
 ('0018_RIGHT_CC', [(1388, 1653), (1894, 2197)]),
 ('0023_RIGHT_CC', [(2574, 2798), (1324, 1545)]),
 ('0026_LEFT_CC', [(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)])]

d = defaultdict(list)
for key, value in data:
    d[key] = list(set(d[key] + value))
```

---

**EDIT**: I changed answer of @JST99 a bit and now it uses a `set` for `in` checks, then adds value to a list. This is faster on large data sets, but for your current data answer of @JST99 is faster.

```py
from collections import defaultdict


data = [('0023_RIGHT_CC', [(2574, 2798), (1324, 1545)]),
 ('0021_LEFT_CC', [(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(911, 1135), (0, 86)]),
 ('0026_LEFT_CC', [(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)]),
 ('0021_RIGHT_CC', [(2170, 2314), (1642, 1795)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)]),
 ('0021_LEFT_CC', [(1180, 1420), (883, 1140)]),
 ('0021_RIGHT_CC', [(2170, 2314), (1642, 1795)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(911, 1135), (0, 86)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1679, 1833), (964, 1102)]),
 ('0106_LEFT_CC', [(1091, 1198), (65, 160)]),
 ('0018_RIGHT_CC', [(1388, 1653), (1894, 2197)]),
 ('0023_RIGHT_CC', [(2574, 2798), (1324, 1545)]),
 ('0026_LEFT_CC', [(3738, 3968), (2144, 2352)])]


d = defaultdict(list)
s = defaultdict(set)
for key, value in data:
    s_value = tuple(value) # lists are unhasable, so we will use tuple
    if s_value not in s[key]: 
        d[key].append(value)
        s[key].add(s_value)

del s # we dont need s anymore
```

Comment: sorry this is not the one I mentioned... I want to preserve the square bracket tuples **[(911, 1135), (0, 86)]**. repeated square bracket tuples must be avoided.